# Unable to install Blackfire PHP on Codeship

Tags: php, heroku, codeship, blackfire

I try to deploy my PHP application to Heroku through Codeship.
Heroku requires to add `ext-blackfire` to my `composer.json` and it results in a crash on Codeship at `composer install`.

```
The requested PHP extension ext-blackfire ~1.18 is missing from your system. 
Install or enable PHP's blackfire extension.
```

How can I install Blackfire extension on Codeship?

Comment: Which parts of blackfire to you need for your builds? If you require the PHP extension only, you can get a version specific download link from https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation, which you can then include in a script to download the `.so` file during the build, and put it into the correct location on the build VMs. That script could look similar to https://gist.github.com/mlocher/a1f4ef6cef5522fef00a5fe9ab302e5f, though I got an Authentication Denied error when trying to download the extension via `wget`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install your dependencies through `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`, which ignores any missing extensions. See the docs (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) for more details.